# convert XML to XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, ant

I am trying to write an XSLT transformation to convert XML to XML , but I am stuck in some issues , Can you please help me with this

Input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<deployment-profile>

<application dp-app-name="helloworld">
        <app-standalonecluster>ctccfg</app-standalonecluster>
        <cluster-members>2</cluster-members>
            <members-info>
               <ip-address>10.94.44.54</ip-address>
               <member-name>ctccfg-goad1-1</member-name>
            </members-info>
            <members-info>
               <ip-address>10.94.44.55</ip-address>
               <member-name>ctccfg-goad2-1</member-name>
            </members-info>
</application>
<application dp-app-name="heyworld1">
        <app-standalonecluster>manthani</app-standalonecluster>
        <cluster-members>2</cluster-members>
            <members-info>
               <ip-address>10.26.24.56</ip-address>
               <member-name>middleoffice-goad1-1</member-name>
            </members-info>
            <members-info>
               <ip-address>10.26.24.57<ip-address>
               <member-name>manthani-goad2-1</member-name>
            </members-info>
</application>

</deployment-profile>
```

Expected OUTPUT XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ant antfile="simple.xml" target="application" dir=".">
   <property name="application.name" value="helloworld"/>
   <property name="cluster.members" value="2"/>
   <property name="members.ipaddress" value="10.94.44.54,10.94.44.55"/>
   <property name="member.names" value="ctccfg-goad1-1,ctccfg-goad2-1"/>
</ant>
```

XSLT Trasnformation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<ant antfile="simple.xml" target="application" dir=".">
<xsl:for-each select="$DeployProfile/deployment-profile/application[@dp-app-name="helloworld"] ">
   <xsl:element name="property">
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="'application.name'" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="value">
            <xsl:value-of select="./@dp-app-name" />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>

    <xsl:element name="property">
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="'members.ipaddress'" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="value">
            <xsl:for-each select="$DeployProfile/deployment-profile/application[@dp-app-name=helloworld]/members-info ">
                  <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="position()=last()"> 
                             <xsl:value-of select="." />
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="concat(./@ip-address,',')" />
                        </xsl:otherwise>   
                   </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>  
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="property">
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="'members.ipaddress'" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="value">
            <xsl:for-each select="$DeployProfile/deployment-profile/application[@dp-app-name=helloworld]/members-info ">
                  <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="position()=last()"> 
                            <xsl:value-of select="." />
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="concat(./@member-name,',')" />
                        </xsl:otherwise>   
                  </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>  
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>

</xsl:for-each>
</ant>
```

But this seems to be not working , i am doing XSLT for the first time , Can some one please guide me if I am missing anything

Comment: Your stylesheet needs to have at least one **template**: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_templates.asp

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to add the repaired XML here as there's only one mistake (missing closing tag) -

```
<ip-address>10.26.24.57<ip-address>
```

should be

```
<ip-address>10.26.24.57</ip-address>
```

Following XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml"/> 
<xsl:template match="/*">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="application[@dp-app-name='helloworld']"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="application[@dp-app-name='helloworld']">
<ant antfile="simple.xml" target="application" dir=".">
  <xsl:element name="property">
   <xsl:attribute name="name">
    <xsl:value-of select="'application.name'" />
   </xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:attribute name="value">
    <xsl:value-of select="./@dp-app-name" />
   </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:element>
  <xsl:element name="property">
    <xsl:attribute name="name">
     <xsl:value-of select="'cluster.members'" />
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="value">
     <xsl:value-of select="./cluster-members" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:element>
  <xsl:element name="property">
   <xsl:attribute name="name">
    <xsl:value-of select="'members.ipaddress'" />
   </xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:attribute name="value">
    <xsl:for-each select="./members-info/ip-address ">
      <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="position()=last()"> 
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space(.),',')" />
       </xsl:otherwise>   
      </xsl:choose>
     </xsl:for-each>  
   </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:element>
  <xsl:element name="property">
   <xsl:attribute name="name">
    <xsl:value-of select="'members.name'"/>
   </xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:attribute name="value">
    <xsl:for-each select="./members-info/member-name">
     <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="position()=last()"> 
       <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space(.),',')" />
      </xsl:otherwise>   
     </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>  
   </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:element>
 </ant>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML ouput:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ant antfile="simple.xml" target="application" dir=".">
 <property name="application.name" value="helloworld"/>
 <property name="cluster.members" value="2"/>
 <property name="members.ipaddress" value="10.94.44.54,10.94.44.55"/>
 <property name="members.name" value="ctccfg-goad1-1,ctccfg-goad2-1"/>  
</ant>
```

As you noticed that you're new into XSLT, I don't want to go into detail here as there are many online resources. But as there wasn't too much to adjust from your example XSLT: above XSLT has 2 templates. The first one matches the whole XML - `<xsl:template match="/*">`. In this template, I apply a second template to the helloworld-application - `<xsl:apply-templates select="application[@dp-app-name='helloworld']"/>`. Meaning - I select only this application and apply templates to it. As there is a matching template - `<xsl:template match="application[@dp-app-name='helloworld']">` - the application is the current node of this template and will be processed from this template. In case there wouldn't be a matching template, the ouput XML would just be the pure text with many spaces. For illustration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    ctccfg
    2

           10.94.44.54
           ctccfg-goad1-1


           10.94.44.55
           ctccfg-goad2-1
```

To get rid of undesired spaces, I've used the function `normalize-space()` at some places. You can just check on your own how the ouput would look like in case this function wouldn't be applied.

Some references: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XSLT/apply-templates

Comment: Thank you very much matthias_h, I would definitely spend enough time to learn this more

Comment: @user3403584 Glad if that was of any help for you. Sorry to ask, but in case given answer worked for you, would you mind to accept it so the question is marked as closed? Sorry in case you receive this twice, but in first answer to your comment I forgot to add your username in front.